# How do I open a drop menu from a button in action bar

Tags: android, button, drop-down-menu, overflow

I'm developing an app for android which needs to have a button in the Action Bar(near the overflow) that opens a drop menu as the menu that comes out by clicking on the overflow button. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is adding an item to the action bar by filling the associated inflated XML file.
On the res/menu/action_bar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_popup"
        android:title="A popup example"
        app:showAsAction="always" // Do not forget to put showAsAction to always so that this item will not be grouped with the overflow
        android:visible="true">
        <menu>
            // Your popup items will be inserted programmatically here by adding item.getSubMenu().add(...) (see the code below)
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item>
        // The overflow items. They all will be hidden here (you put the showAsAction to never)
        ...
    </item>
</menu>
```

On your activity you can inflate this menu :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Then, populate the items on the menu and handle the click event on those items:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.new_popup)
{
    item.getSubMenu().add(0, itemId, order, "your text").setIcon(your icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
 // Handle this item click event
}
    // Add more items!
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want both buttons in the action bar, the overflow button and the new button which I'd like to insert. If I code as you suggest me, I replace the overflow button with the new button.

Comment: I have edited my code, you can see where your new popup items will be added.
In your picture below, you have a "+" item, all the items inserted programmatically will be added in the submenu of the "new_popup" item.
The rest will be inserted in the overflow group.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The "plus" button in the action bar needs to open a menu as the one that comes out by clicking the overflow button. Eventually I need both menus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dropdown menu navigation in action bar to do that, here is the [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) also see this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/), hope this helps :)